# Propel: Class 'Propel' not found in PropelMigrationManager.php

Tags: php, propel

I am new in using Propel. While generating migration using command

```
propel-gen diff
```

I am getting the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Propel' not found in /home/paritosh/Source/project/external_lib/propel/generator/lib/util/PropelMigrationManager.php on line 64
```

Don't know why this error is happening? Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using a development version of Propel.
Use the latest stable version by downloading here: http://files.propelorm.org/

I had the same problem and solved using this version:
http://files.propelorm.org/propel-1.6.9.zip